# Gett battery temperature in percentage

Tags: android

The below code is used to get battery temperature.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
  int temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
  ....
}
};
```

However, I want to show the battery temperature in the percentage. How can I can find `EXTRA_SCALE` for battery temperature or max value of the battery temperature?

Comment: What did you mean with "battery temperature in percentage"? Battery charge level?

Comment: its on degree Centigrade , so i dont think there is extra_scale for it. check for "maximum battery temperature" of ur battry brand

Comment: how i can check max battery temperature programmtically

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_TEMPERATURE - as far as i can tell there is no max temperature, or at least none in the device you could read